# Proving the union of conjugates of a subgroup is not the whole group

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

I know this question is discussed several times on this site, but I am trying to use a slightly different method than the ones already provided to solve it. Please would you check whether my solution is correct?

I have considered an action from a group $G$ to the set $X$ of all the subgroups of $G$ defined by $(g, H) \to gHg^{-1}$, where $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, and proven that $|Orb_G(H)| \le |G/H|$. Now I considered the case where $H \ne G$, and tried to argue that $|Orb_G(H)| \le |G/H| \lt |G|$. But I worry that the $|Orb_G(H)|$ counts a number of subgroups of $G$, whereas $|G|$ counts elements, so I don't think it's valid. In that case, please could I have some help?

Please note, I need to find a way to follow on from the weak inequality already proven.

EDIT: $G/H$ denotes the set of left cosets.

Comment: Proving that the size of the orbit is less than the order of $G$ does *not* prove that $G$ is not the union of the conjugates of $H$. I doubt that this idea will be successful: you can have a very large group be the union of three subgroups (though they aren't conjugate to each other, of course), so I don't see how bounding the number of subgroups of a particular type can help you show that the union is not the whole group, unless you get that the number is less than $3$ (as no group is a union of two or fewer proper subgroups).

Comment: In any case, the inequality that $|Orb_G(H)|\lt |G|$ holds for nontrivial $H$ is certainly true: the size of $Orb_G(H)$ is equal to the index of the normalizer of $H$ in $G$, hence is bounded above by $|G/H|$ as you note, and this is certainly bounded by $|G|$, since $|H|>1$ and $|G/H| = |G|/|H|$. (I'm assuming you use $G/H$ to denote the set of cosets, not the quotient, since $H$ is not assumed to be normal). The fact that you are counting different things does not prevent you from comparing their sizes.

Comment: $G/H$ does denote the set of left cosets, and I shall edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Would this work: proving that if $H \ne G$, $|H||Orb_G(H)| \lt G$? This could be done by showing $|H| \lt |Stab(H)|$, I believe, so we only need find one element not already in $H$ that stabilises $H$.

Comment: Ahhh that's incorrect. Since we're dealing with the union, and all the conjugate subgroups share ${e}$, an identity, we know the number of elements in that union is at most $1+(|H|-1)|Orb_G(H)|$ and then it's basically done from there. Thank you very much for your help @ArturoMagidin, I will up vote your comments.